# OpenCV gradient with missing data

Tags: opencv

I am working on a task where the image I have presents missing data, I wish to obtain the gradient without internal boundary issues.

The idea is to build a height map out of point cloud data (done) and then evaluate the slopes using a gradient function, however the points are sparse and thus the image presents missing data.

The first approach I tried was to use dilation in order to grow the area by some pixels, then apply the gradient filter and finally mask the boundaries to remove fabricated data, but it seems to erodes slopes as well:

[image: Left: actual height map, right: dilated map]

On this picture a height map is gererated from a point cloud which in turn comes from a stereo camera system, the camera is facing a steep wall. On the left is the height map and on the right is the dilated map. On the right side it seems the wall has been "pushed back".

What would be the best approach to eliminate the internal border conditions? I thought about dilating the values with a special function that ignores the "non-available pixels" (perhaps represented by 0 or -1) and takes the average of the surrounding available pixel values (if available). Is there such a function in OpenCV?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but may be you can interpolate missing data with nearest neighbourhood. Another way solve diifferential equation using boundary condition